# Typing several varargin arguments

Tags: matlab, matrix, variadic-functions

I have a function that uses varargin as its input, but when I have to call this function, I create several matrices, and it's very inefficient to type all of them on the command window.

First I use a function that creates, for example, 50 2x2 matrices. And when I have to use this other function, I have to call one by one, for example: `rich(A(:,:,1), A(:,:,2), (...), A(:,:,50))`

Is there a easiest way to call these matrices without the need to type one by one?
Something like `rich(A(:,:,1:50) or rich(A(:,:,1):A(:,:,50))` (I know this is not possible, but I was looking for something like this...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
%# random matrix of size 2x2x50
A = rand(2,2,50);

%# split by slices along the third dimension: AA = {A(:,:,1); ...; A(:,:,50)}
AA = mat2cell(A, 2, 2, ones(1,size(A,3)));
AA = AA(:);

%# call function, expanding into a comma-separated list
rich(AA{:})
```

Comment: Here is a link to the relevant docs: [Comma-Separated Lists](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html)